# Is it a good idea to connect aluminum AC mains wires by soldering

Tags: soldering, mains

Provided I have an appropriate flux for aluminum and I'm able to solder the wires will this connection be durable?

I'm not sure if it will corrode or not considering aluminum and the solder (60-40 solder) are different metals.

Comment: Just going to guess that since copper mains are never soldered, aluminum won't be allowed, either.

Comment: @gbarry, I have read that copper mains wires are soldered sometimes in the US. I am not an electrician, but I have never seen soldered mains wire. Just read about it.

Comment: In what country are the wires located? Aluminum mains wires have been the subject of many lawsuits in the US and have caused several house or apartment fires. Aluminum mains wires are considered to be "bad news." If there is any way you can replace them with copper wires, that would probably be your best bet. Otherwise it is time to do some extensive research. Personally, I would join them with "wire nuts" rated for aluminum wire.

Comment: This is a 30yo appartment building built in the USSR times. Aluminum is not used here anymore.

Comment: @axk if it's not used anymore, how comes you want to solder it? I don't understand :(

Comment: @axk is from Belarus, aluminium wires were in common usage during last Soviet periods. I do not think you will be able to solder aluminium properly, tried in the past and did not succeed :) I recommend replacing the wiring with copper one. It is investment and time, but you will solve many problems with it. And you **can** solder copper wires!

Comment: @Anonymous I know – in post-war Germany, Alu wires were common, too, but they were ripped out ASAP.

Comment: The problem with aluminium is that it creeps. Really, really badly. You screw a terminal tight as you can, come back a year later and it's loose. And then the fire starts. I too would be inclined to just get rid of it if possible. As to soldering, there is nothing wrong with it, indeed the only connections you can leave inaccessible here in the UK under the regulations are soldered (or brazed, welded etc) ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Provided I have an appropriate flux for aluminum and I'm able to solder the wires will this connection be durable?

That's nearly impossible. You can weld aluminium under protective atmosphere (inert gas welding), but you cannot solder it with normal solder. Or at least, I've never seen anyone succeed (and by god, I tried to use alu sheet metal as ground planes). I've heard it's possible, but you'll need a special solder, which seems to be very expensive.

> will this connection be durable?

If you used the right solder and technique, probably, yes. But since that would be your first alu solder joints: No. Good soldering takes practice, even on much simpler materials like copper. Don't expect good results on your first try :)

Also, other aluminium connections won't be durable: read the comments, it creeps, and that's not a good property for a wire that you want to screw in or stick in to some locking connector.

**But:** don't use aluminium wires. There's a reason they aren't used anymore today, and it's very simple, and physically inevitable:

1. Aluminium doesn't like being bent as much as e.g. copper does. You don't want your wire to slightly break when installing it, because that breaking point will have a higher resistance, and get hot, and burn your house down.
2. Aluminium generally has a much higher resistance than copper. You just convert your electrical energy to heat. Using [copper-clad aluminium wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper-clad_aluminium_wire) does make sense in some cases, but that cable needs to be thicker than a copper cable carrying the same current (and usually isn't even cheaper, in the end, for installation cables). You find these types of cables in free-hanging high-voltage supply lines – they aren't good for installation, because you can't bend them as much as copper cable (see 1.), and because they are bigger than their copper alternatives.

In other words, *don't use aluminium cabling*.

Comment: I presume the issue with trying to solder alu is that it's a highly reactive metal, so the surface isn't aluminium, it's a few molecules thick of aluminium oxide that forms instantly when alu is exposed to the air.

Comment: Actually, there are spring clamps, e.g. from WAGO, which are rated for copper and aluminium. But before inserting an aluminium wire, put the WAGO contact paste into the clamp.

Comment: @IanBland exactly. And heating it up doesn't help with the oxidation! What you really need to do is generate a small "puddle" of liquid/semi-liquid aluminium and mechanically connect that – but that's not soldering, that's welding. I don't know how alu soldering works, but my guess is that it contains some Fluoride or similarly aggressive compound that reduces the aluminium oxide and swims up.

Comment: @MarcusMüller -- for below oh 40A or so, you're right -- but Al is common for service and feeder cabling at 40+A sizes and works quite well when treated with the appropriate respect -- there was a changeover from AA-1350 to AA-8000 series alloys for the wire itself which helped tremendously in this regard.